# Retrieve specific JSON data in Node JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm totally new to Angular JS and Node JS. I have several JSON files (Language translations) in server side. According to client request I need to retrieve data of JSON file. If user request french language , I need to retrieve data of that particular JSON file. This is what I tried based on search. It's not working. Can someone help me with proper method?

```
function getTranslations (
  request /* : Request<null, {
    nextToken?: string
  }, {}> */,
  response /* : Object */
)  {
  request.headers = request.headers || {}
  return authentication.authenticate(request.headers.authorization)
    .then((tokenPayload) => authorisation.authorise(tokenPayload.username, permissions.TRANSLATE))
    .then((authorised) => {
      if (!authorised) {
        return Promise.reject(boom.forbidden('Message'))
      }

    const options = {  
        url: 'files/translations/',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
        }
    };

    app.get("/:getValue", function(req, res)  { 
    request(options, function(err, response, body) {  
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json); 
        res.json(request.json) 
    });    
    });

    app.listen(3000, function() {  
        console.log("My API is running...");
    });

    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are many ways to go about it. I'll make some assumptions regarding your question it wasn't clear. First, I assume, there are many json files like en.json for english, fr.json for french etc.

Now, if a user requests, "english", he should get the data of en.json. And same way for fr.json.

What you can do is create a file called `translation.js` with the following:

```
module.exports = {
    ENGLISH: require('./en.json'),
    FRENCH: require('./fr.json')
};
```

Then in your router you can send the data based on the parameter passed:

```
//app.js
var translation = require('./translation.js');

app.get(/:value, (req, res) => {
    if (req.params.value === 'french') {
        return res.status(200).json(translation.FRENCH);
    }

    return res.status(200).json(translation.ENGLISH);
});
```

Or you can use a package for i18n - https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. My route has defined in a seperate file. I cannot use app.get here.Then how do I modify this?

Comment: You can require that file anywhere and use it as per your case.